Best way to merge after base branch was squashed into main branch
I have a minor git issue that keeps coming up. I have a feature that's in a PR, and then another feature that is dependent on it.The base for the second feature is squash merged. The second feature now contains commits that are the original.
             /C
       A - B
master/

Becomes:
      A - B -C
    /   
master - D

where D is the squashed A and B.
What's the best way to merge C into master at this point, while droping A and B. I have been doing git rebase -i master and then manually dropping the commits A and B, and then creating a new branch, but this is messy. People havea already reviewed C and we lose the discussion history.

Not sure about the DV here. Maybe because it's very likely a dup of other questions. (In fact I just answered another question like this last week, though in that one OP didn't confirm if the problem was due to a squash merge, but it likely was.)

But to answer your question, you need to git fetch and then rebase like this (with your branch already checked out): git rebase B --onto origin/master  In words, that says, "Rebase all of the commits reachable by my branch, which are not reachable by B, and replay them, one by one, on top of  the latest remote copy of master." Essentially it's all your commits minus B, which leaves just C.

If we don't find a good dup, I'd be OK with answering this question, since it is concise and well written.

“I have a minor git issue that keeps coming up.” Your workflow for dealing with it is already pretty good (TTT’s is more streamlined). But it is already tedious when you know exactly what commits that you should drop. Right? Which means that it will be even more tedious when things get complicated and people lose track of the correspondence. So if this “keeps coming up”? You either need some bespoke keep-up-with-squashes tooling or else whoever set up this Squash Policy needs to be put in charge of fixing up every feature branch. Then let’s see how long the policy lasts.

@Guildenstern From the POV of each feature branch that has the pattern of starting from another un-merged feature branch, there is only 1 starting commit ID that needs to be "remembered" per branch. I have offered some ideas in an answer for tracking that. Note this works even if you are chaining many branches together. (With the caveat that the PRs are completed in the same order that the branches were created. But if that's not the case, then the branches could have, and should, started from master instead of another branch...)

I found this related long-form answer

@TTT I overestimated the difficulty of finding squashes/updating a branch with git-rebase(1) / underestimated git-rebase(1).

The problem with your rebase command, as you realized, is that you are including commits in the list that no longer exist. There is an easier way to remove them than by using interactive mode:
git fetch # this updates your local copy of origin/master
git rebase B --onto origin/master

In words, that says:

Rebase all of the commits reachable by my branch, which are not reachable by B, and replay them, one by one, on top of the latest remote copy of master.

Essentially it's all your commits minus B, which leaves just C.
Tip: The reason this happens is the combination of starting from a commit that is not yet on master, and also squashing that commit into master instead of using a regular merge. If this pattern happens often, which it sounds like it does, it may help to keep track of the commit you are starting from in a simple way. Here are two ideas for tracking it:

After creating your branch: add an empty commit as the first commit on your branch: git commit --allow-empty -m "wip: starting here".
Include the starting commit ID in the branch name, for example: git switch -c my-feature-start-commit-abcd1234 some-other-branch-name

When it comes time to do your advanced rebase with --onto, the first argument to the rebase (represented by commit B in the question) could be quickly substituted with the commit ID of the wip commit in #1, or the commit ID specified in your branch name from #2.

Overall great answer but I strongly recommend to never, never ever using rebase command forms that depends on what the current branch is. First sooner or later you will be burnt by the current branch being something other than you assumed, and secondly the rebase commands are more intuitive and easier to understand when being explicit: git rebase --onto commit_D commit_B branch_with_commit_C means move the branch with commits from (not including) B on top of D.

The above explicit rebase command is basically the same as git checkout commit_D; git cherry-pick commit_B..branch_with_commit_C only with additional modification of the head of the branch in question.

@hlovdal I used to prefer the rebase syntax with --onto first, but after a few years of that I changed my preference bc rebase takes 1, 2, or 3 args, and by putting --onto as the third arg the order is always the same. For example, git rebase origin/main, or git rebase origin/main my-branch, or git rebase origin/main my-branch --onto origin/release. You're right that in my example I left out the second argument, and I only did that bc OP used the 1 argument syntax which I think is the norm. I'm guessing you only meant that in the context of when using --onto?

@hlovdal Note that all rebase commands could be done with a checkout or reset followed by a series of cherry-picks. The only difference is that rebase can be done in a single command, and rebase also offers the optional interactive mode. In fact, oftentimes when teaching rebase I will first show how to achieve the desired outcome with cherry-picks first, and then show how to do a one-liner with the equivalent rebase command. When people aren't quite comfortable with rebase I suggest using cherry-pick instead because it's usually easier to understand.
